# Batch – Delete Characters in a String

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, string

For example, I have the following path:
`"C:\Windows\Example\001 Example\005 Example"`
I must extract the `"005 Example"` from this string.
I've tried it with `"set path=%path:~0,11%"`, but the path can also be `"C:\Windows\Example\001 Example\005 Example_2"`

What I need is to cut the string after the last "\"

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  How does `%path:~0,11%` help you get `005 Example`?  It looks like it is designed to get `"C:\Windows`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, don’t use `path` as a variable name. 
Windows Command Prompt
(unlike most components of Unix, including the shells)
treats variable names in a case-insensitive way,
so `path` is the same as `PATH`, which is your execution search path,
and if you assign something random to that, you’ll be in a world of hurt.

Use the `%variable:str1=str2%` form. 
(I presume that you know that `set /?` documents these forms.) 
This one is substitution:

```
C:\> set play=food

C:\> echo %play:foo=bar%
bard

C:\> set animal=cat

C:\> echo %animal:at=ow%
cow
```

This supports a *very limited* pattern-matching capability;
`%variable:*str1=str2%` will find and delete
everything up to and including the first occurrence of *`str1`*
and replace it with *`str2`*. 
In particular, `%variable:*\=%` will replace
everything up to and including the first `\` with null. 
E.g., if `%pathname%` is `C:\Windows\Example\001 Example\005 Example`,
then `%pathname:*\=%` will evaluate to
`Windows\Example\001 Example\005 Example` (without the `C:\`). 
If your pathname will always have four levels, you can do

```
for %%I in (%pathname%) do set tempname=%%~I
set tempname=%tempname:*\=%
set tempname=%tempname:*\=%
set tempname=%tempname:*\=%
set tempname=%tempname:*\=%
set basename=%tempname%
echo %basename%
```

The `for` statement is a bit of a kludge. 
It’s a loop that is guaranteed to execute exactly once
with index variable `%%I` set to the value of `%pathname%`<sup>1</sup>. 
Then it assigns `%%~I` to `tempname`. 
`%%~I` is the value of `%%I` (i.e., the value of `%pathname%`)
except, if that string begins and ends with quote (`"`) characters,
they are removed. 
If you’re sure that `%pathname%` doesn’t begin and end with quotes
(e.g., because you’ve already done this, or something equivalent),
you can skip this step and just start by saying `set tempname=%pathname%`.

If the pathname has an indeterminate number of levels, do

```
for %%I in (%pathname%) do set tempname1=%%~I
:loop
set tempname2=%tempname1:*\=%
if not %tempname1% == %tempname2% ( set tempname1=%tempname2% & goto loop )
set basename=%tempname1%
echo %basename%
```

which loops until there are no `\`s left.
______________
<sup>1</sup>
Actually, its behavior may be more complex if `%pathname%` is null (empty),
or if it contains wildcard (pattern-matching) characters like `?` and `*`. 
There may be other peculiar cases that I haven’t found. 
(Please let me know if there’s a cleaner way to deal with quotes.)

---

Warning: I’ve observed `%variable:str1=str2%`
to behave oddly if `%variable%` is null.

Comment: Thanks verry Much. `set tempname=%tempname:*\=%` was what i searched for.